# trace of the product of an almost complex structure and a symmetric matrix in dimension 2

Tags: linear-algebra

Let J and A be 2x2 matrices, s.t. J²=-Id and A is symmetric, what can I say about tr(JA), is it possibly zero? I have been playing around with this but haven found a way to prove or disprove, it actually seems possibly true, any good idea is more than welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $J$ to be rotation by $\pi/2$, to mimic multiplication by $i$,
$$
 J = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
whatever $A$ is, $JA$ has trace zero,
$$
 J\begin{bmatrix}a & b \cr b & c \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix} -b & -c \cr a & b \end{bmatrix}.
$$
[edit:] The general case can be summarized
by saying
that the trace of $JA$ is zero iff there is
an eigenvector $u$ of $A$, such that $Ju$ is also an eigenvector
of $A$. No time to write all details, but you can start with eigenvectors $u,v$ of $A$. Then
$$ 
 Ju = eu+fv, \qquad Jv = gu+hv
$$
for some numbers $e,f,g,h$. You argue that
$JA$ is similar to
$$
 \begin{bmatrix} e & f \cr g & h \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 \cr 0 & \mu \end{bmatrix},
$$
and that you must have $g = -(1+e^2)/f$, $h = -g$.
Then multiplying the matrices you see that
the trace is zero iff $\lambda = \mu$ or $e = 0$.

In the first case, the eigenvalues of $A$ are equal so $A$ is a multiple of the identity so that
$Ju$ is automatically an eigenvector of $A$. In the second case you have $Ju = fv \ne 0$ and you are done.

Comment: I think I finally understood the proof, there is a typo : h=-g should actualy be h=-e, I just wanted to point it out in case someone needs the answer in the future. Thanks a lot!!!